# Formatting Equation Output Neatly

Tags: output-formatting, series-expansion

I looked around and couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, so I'm sorry if this is a bad question - I'm pretty new to mathematica. I wrote a program to help me compute some annoying series expansions, and the output is pretty ugly, for example:

$\epsilon ^2 \left(\left(a_{5,1} a_{6,1}+a_{1,1} \left(a_{2,1}+a_{6,1}\right)\right) X_{1,2}+\left(a_{5,1} \left(a_{9,1}+a_{10,1}\right)+a_{1,1} \left(a_{3,1}+a_{9,1}+a_{10,1}\right)\right) X_{1,3}+\left(a_{5,1} \left(a_{7,1}+a_{8,1}\right)+a_{1,1} \left(a_{4,1}+a_{7,1}+a_{8,1}\right)\right) X_{1,4}+\left(a_{6,1} \left(a_{9,1}+a_{10,1}\right)+a_{2,1} \left(a_{3,1}+a_{9,1}+a_{10,1}\right)\right) X_{2,3}+\left(a_{6,1} \left(a_{7,1}+a_{8,1}\right)+a_{2,1} \left(a_{4,1}+a_{7,1}+a_{8,1}\right)\right) X_{2,4}+a_{3,1} \left(a_{4,1}+a_{7,1}+a_{8,1}\right) X_{3,4}\right)+\epsilon  \left(X_3 \epsilon  a_{3,2}+X_4 \epsilon  a_{4,2}+X_1 \left(\epsilon  a_{1,2}+\epsilon  a_{5,2}+a_{1,1}+a_{5,1}\right)+X_2 \left(\epsilon  a_{2,2}+\epsilon  a_{6,2}+a_{2,1}+a_{6,1}\right)+X_4 \epsilon  a_{7,2}+X_4 \epsilon  a_{8,2}+X_3 \epsilon  a_{9,2}+X_3 \epsilon  a_{10,2}+X_3 a_{3,1}+X_4 a_{4,1}+X_4 a_{7,1}+X_4 a_{8,1}+X_3 a_{9,1}+X_3 a_{10,1}\right)$

I'm wondering if there's a way to have it output this in a more readable way, for example, something like:

$X_{1}*(coefficients)\\
X_{2}*(coefficients)\\
...\\
X_{1,2}*(coefficents)\\
etc...$

Is there a way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Please include the *Mathematica* code that produced your output for the convenience of those who wish to help.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be something like this:

```
   Column@Apply[List, 
      Collect[Sum[Expand[(a - b)^i] X[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}], _X] /.
       y_*z_X :> Row[{Style[z, Bold, Red, 22] , "*(", y, ")"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So in this case, X[1,1] is my $X_{1}$? And I'm slightly confused how to modify this code to match my case - I'm not sure what would go in for "List", for example, as I have no list.

Comment: So what do you have? Subscript? Please enter a Mathematica expression into the question. Please also read a bit about Mathematica, FullForm, Apply, Plus, List, etc. Or follow one of the online tutorials or go to a training or some such.

Comment: Yes, I'm just using subscripts. The subscripts do not correspond to a matrix or anything (I see now where that confusion may have come from), but rather each $X_{i}$ is a vector field, and each $X_{i,j}$ is a Lie bracket of two vector fields. I've done some tutorials and read about Mathematica, I just never found what I was looking for.

Comment: Just post your program to do the series expansions. Tthen people will help you.